# Gradle/Java replace text

Tags: java, regex, gradle

Is it possible to use regex to convert urls in css files in the way demonstrated below? I don't want to hardcode font names.

from:

```
url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
```

to:

```
url("#{resource['css:../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype')
```

And this is what I currently have:

```
task fixCSSResources << {
    FileTree cssFiles = fileTree("src/main/webapp") {
        include "**/*.css"
    }
    cssFiles.each { File cssFile ->
        String content = cssFile.getText("UTF-8")
        // what to do here?
        cssFile.write(content, "UTF-8")
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the patterns in the text? Will it always be `url(something) format(something)`?

Comment: @SongCGGao here's example http://pastebin.com/VzmaFrMJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you just want to format `url(something)`, this should do what you want:

```
String regex = "url\\('([^']*?\\.(eot|ttf|fnt))(.*?)'\\)";
//                   font file formats^           
content = content.replaceAll(regex, "url(\"#{resource['css:$1']}$3\")");
```

**EDIT**: forgot to escape some characters.

Comment: Where are you specifying the files here?